# Using the split method to separate categories into columns from a text file

Tags: python, text, split, multiple-columns

so I'm having trouble trying to read a file in the python programmer by separating lines into columns depending on their categories. For instance, the lines for `name` are different names under it, and then the lines for `Occupation` have different titles of occupations under it, and the lines for `location` have different cities under it. I need to open up the file that has all these lines and separate them into 3 columns based on these three categories. I tried the `split`, `rsplit`, `splittinglines` methods but none of them work. What am I doing wrong? For instance, this is what I'm doing:

```
fhand = open('names.txt')
for line in fhand:
line = line.rsplit()
print(line)"
```

The file looks like this:

```
Name:
Pat M.
Jorge M.
Johnny N.
Occupation:
Professor
Web Developer
Computer Scientist
Location:
Delta College
Pleasanton
Lawrence Livermore Lab
```

Comment: share some sample text before anyone is able to help you

Comment: a text file is not a proper format for this kind of data. you should save it as a CSV or Excelfile then process it using libraries like pandas.

Comment: Arashsyh: my professor gave me and other classmates a text file for this assignment, hence my question here. I will answer my own question with this file as an example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if splitting lines is in itself that helpful since each line only has one piece of data; you need to collect data across multiple lines.  Give this a whirl:

```
from typing import Dict, List, Optional
from collections import defaultdict

column: Optional[str] = None
columns: Dict[str, List[str]] = defaultdict(list)
with open('names.txt') as fhand:
    for line in fhand:
        line = line.strip()

        # Is this the start of a new column?
        if line[-1] == ":":
            column = line[:-1]
        # If not, append this to the current column.
        elif column is not None:
            columns[column].append(line)
print(columns)
```

Comment: Thank you, but it did not come out the way I expected; instead, each word came out next to the other, with the exception that for each category, each corresponding line was between parenthesis. It's very hard, I know, but I don't know how my professor could ask his students to do this assignment using a text file instead of an easier app. Thank you for your help anyway.

Comment: I was just showing you how to read the file into a data structure that has all the information you need in an easily-accessible format.  Outputting it the way you want is up to you (it's the easiest part, but only you know how exactly it has to be done since it wasn't part of the question).  Good luck!  :)